# dataframe replace prevent replacing incorrect int32 fields when int64 values supplied

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Question: How to replace all specific int64 values in the data frame but avoid wrongly replacing unequal int32 values.

Dataframe replaces int32 values wrongly when large int64 values supplied.
Below I created **minimal** example, where I would like to replace all fields with large value to -1. Given that all data is zero, nothing should be updated.
However column 'a' becomes -1 after the replace

```
import pandas
import numpy
dtype = [('a','int32'), ('b','int64'), ('c','float32')]
index = ['x', 'y']
columns = ['a','b','c']
values = numpy.zeros(2, dtype=dtype)
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(values, index=index)
df2.replace(-9223372036854775808, -1)
```

output is:

```
     a  b     c
x   -1  0   0.0
y   -1  0   0.0
```

Edit:

Looks like numpy converts type down, but question is still how to avoid it in data frame conversion?
Note: -9223372036854775808 is HEX 8000000000000000

```
x = numpy.array(-9223372036854775808, dtype='int64')
print('as int32: ', x.astype(numpy.int32))
#produces
#('as int32: ', array(0, dtype=int32))
```

Comment: I believe this example is even more minimal: `ds=pandas.Series([0,0,0],dtype='int32'); ds.replace(-9223372036854775808, -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly observed that the problem is caused by the type narrowing. Why don't you replace only those columns that have the matching or at least wide enough data type?

```
df2[['b','c']].replace(-9223372036854775808, -1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: In real life I have large data frame with large and random number of columns, I was hoping to avoid iterating on individual columns

Comment: There is no need to iterate. Get a list of all columns of interest: `int64cols=df2.columns[df2.dtypes=='int64']`, then update just them: `df2[int64cols].replace(-9223372036854775808, -1, inplace=True)`.

Comment: Alternatively, promote all int32 columns to int64. It won't hurt, except that the frame will need more space.

Comment: The second suggestion to get list of all 'typed' columns worked for me, with a small tweak. I am accepting the answer.